# Not getting intended results when using subprocess in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im trying to use subprocess in python2.7.16 on a Mac but I'm currently getting the wrong output when running `self._execute` and I am not sure why. The output that I am meant to be getting is ***(True, 'Python 2.7.16\n')*** but I am getting ***(False, 'Python 2.7.16\n')***. When I test this code in python3 it works perfectly fine. Is there anything that I am doing wrong or is there anyway to fix this?

```
import os
import subprocess


class Run_Checks:
    def __init__(self):

        print self._execute(['python', '--version'])

    def _execute(self, _cmd):
        process = subprocess.Popen(_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdoutput, stderroutput = process.communicate()

        if stdoutput:
            return True, stdoutput
        return False, stderroutput

def main():
    Run_Checks()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you following the appropriate documentation for subprocess? Perhaps the syntax has changed among major versions of versions used in python 3 vs python 2?

Comment: Why are you using Python 2?

Comment: @AMC Whole framework is written in python 2, need to keep it all the same.